# How to run old mfc program on VS 2013?

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to make this program running on VS 2013. It doesn't help to put the following:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define USE_STANDARD_FILE_FUNCTIONS
```

I still get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Code3C.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(38): warning C4996:        'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC': MBCS support in MFC is deprecated and may be removed in a future     version of MFC.

1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(33) : see     declaration of 'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC'
1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>c:\users\revist\desktop\sallcode\sallcode\code3c\code3c.cpp(76): error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\stdio.h(211) : see declaration of 'fopen'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The program:

CCode3.h:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxdlgs.h>    //dialog boxes
#include "resource.h"
#define n 10

class CCode3C : public CFrameWnd
{
private:
CPoint *pt;
public:
CCode3C();
CCode3C::~CCode3C();
afx_msg void OnFileOpen();
afx_msg void OnFileSave();
afx_msg void OnGenerate();
afx_msg void OnClear();
afx_msg void OnExit();
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

class CMyWinApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};
```

CCode3C.cpp

```
#include "Code3C.h"

CMyWinApp  MyApplication;

BOOL CMyWinApp::InitInstance()
{
CCode3C* pFrame = new CCode3C;
m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
pFrame->UpdateWindow();
return TRUE;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCode3C,CFrameWnd)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILEOPEN,OnFileOpen)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILESAVE,OnFileSave)
ON_COMMAND(ID_GENERATE,OnGenerate)
ON_COMMAND(ID_CLEAR,OnClear)
ON_COMMAND(ID_EXIT,OnExit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CCode3C::CCode3C()
{
Create(NULL, "Code3C: File menus",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CRect(0,0,600,400),
    NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
pt=new CPoint [n+1];
}

CCode3C::~CCode3C()
{
delete pt;
}

void CCode3C::OnClear()
{
CClientDC dc(this);
CRect rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);
CBrush whiteBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
dc.FillRect(&rc,&whiteBrush);
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    pt[i]=CPoint(0,0);
}

void CCode3C::OnGenerate()
{
CClientDC dc(this);
CString str;
time_t seed=time(NULL); 
srand((unsigned)seed);
OnClear();
dc.TextOut(50,50,"Generating Random Numbers");
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    pt[i].x=100+rand()%400; pt[i].y=50+rand()%300;
    str.Format("%d   %d",pt[i].x,pt[i].y);
    dc.TextOut(50,80+20*i,str);
}
}

void CCode3C::OnFileOpen()
{
CClientDC dc(this);
CString str;
CRect rc;
FILE *ifp;
char strFilter[] = {"TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*||"};
CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE,".txt",NULL,0,strFilter);
if (FileDlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
{
    str=FileDlg.GetFileName();
    ifp = fopen(str, "r");
    dc.TextOut(350,50,"File Opened: "+str);
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp,"%d %d",&pt[i].x,&pt[i].y);
        rc=CRect(pt[i].x-30,pt[i].y-30,pt[i].x+30,pt[i].y+30);
        dc.Ellipse(rc);
        rc=CRect(pt[i].x-1,pt[i].y-1,pt[i].x+1,pt[i].y+1);
        dc.Rectangle(rc);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
}
}

void CCode3C::OnFileSave()
{
CClientDC dc(this);
CString str;
FILE *ofp;
char strFilter[] = {"TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*||"};
CFileDialog FileDlg(FALSE,".txt",NULL,0,strFilter);
if( FileDlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
{
    str=FileDlg.GetFileName();
    ofp=fopen(str,"w");
    dc.TextOut(50,20,"File Saved: "+str);
    str.Format("%d",n);
    dc.TextOut(50,50,"Contents: "+str+" randomly generated numbers");
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        fprintf(ofp,"%d  %d\n",pt[i].x,pt[i].y);
    fclose(ofp);
}
}

void CCode3C::OnExit()
{
CCode3C::OnExit();
}
```

Please keep in mind that I am new to programming (started about 4 weeks ago) so answering one of the questions below: Yes I am serious.

Comment: Is that a joke? What do you mean "it doesn't help to put..."??? Describe exactly what the problem is... Oh, and get rid of those X's!

Comment: `void CCode3C::OnExit() { CCode3C::OnExit(); }` Are you serious?

Comment: Yes, I am. Furthermore, this code comes from a book so I should rather say the authors were serious.

Comment: You need to put those definitions at the top of `stdafx.h` if you're using precompiled headers, which is the default.

Comment: so:
     `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`
     `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`
     `#define USE_STANDARD_FILE_FUNCTIONS`

    `#include "stdafx.h"` ?? And do I keep `afxwin.h`?

Comment: Still it says cannot open source file stdafx.h

Comment: Try just using `< >` and not the `.h` file on the included. Also, make sure the compiler can find its header files. You may additionally, need to add libraries.

Comment: If you posted the entire source code then your project is not using a stdafx.h file. So instead put your new #define's before afxwin.h

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The OP said *"this code comes from a book"* - and [it seems it does](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2Ew451VaQRcC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=void+CCode3C::OnExit%28%29&source=bl&ots=SpjJ9djxKy&sig=rzHRjGGZkM47J5jwR8wcz8r7Cds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FZeaVPTzK-LT7Qa9soDYDg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=void%20CCode3C%3A%3AOnExit%28%29&f=false). I can't believe it either though. The authors describe it as *"the formal way for exiting from the program"* !!!

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed sometimes necessary to run old MBCS MFC code on a current Visual Studio release. In that case, downloading the VS MBCS MFC add-on at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251007.aspx should resolve your problem.

Comment: Somehow it worked, I previously installed this pack but did not restart the PC. Anyway, thank you.